# Fetching brightest pixel from a grayscale image

Tags: arrays, matlab, image-processing

I have a grayscale image from which I need to find the top 0.1% brightest pixels.

I tried using a max function on 0.1% of the pixels but it is not giving me correct results.

**Code:**

```
[m,n]=size(image);

num_pixels=m*n;

pixels=floor(num_pixels*0.01)
```

Here, I got some 7000 number in my variable `pixels`. I am not getting how to sort these 7000 pixels because it is just giving me one count. I need to get all the pixel values of this count.

Can anybody suggest how to do this in MATLAB.

Comment: As per first guess, why don't you sort the pixels by value and take the highest 0.1% pixels?

Comment: my code is like this: [m,n]=size(image); num_pixels=m*n;pixels=floor(num_pixels*0.01);. Here i got some 7000 number in my variable pixel. Now i am not getting how to sort this 7000 pixels because it is just giving me one count. i need to get all the pixels value of this count. how to get all the pixel values.

Comment: If you have some code that you tried, kindly place it in the original question.

Comment: First linearize your matrix `image` and then sort (descending order)  `image` and take just the starting 1 to `pixels` values. These would be your 0.1% pixels with highest brightness.

Comment: Do you just want the values of those pixels, or do you also need the locations?

Comment: Thanks Zeeshan for the idea. I have tried this and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the top intensity value this way:

```
  sortedIntensityValues = sort(grayScaleImg(:));  % ascending order
  numPixels = numel(sortedIntensityValues);
  topIntensity = sortedIntensityValues(floor(numPixels*0.999));
```

This way (as mentioned in comments):

```
  sortedIntensityValues = sort(grayScaleImg(:),'descend');  % descending order
  numPixels = numel(sortedIntensityValues);
  topIntensity = sortedIntensityValues(floor(numPixels*0.001));
```

Or, if you have the stats toolbox you can use the `prtcile` function to do it like this:

```
  topIntensity = prctile(grayScaleImg(:),99.9);
```

Here's proof of concept using the third approach:

1. Create some code for you to test:

   ```
   grayScaleImg = rand(4096,4096);
   ```
2. Obtain the intensity for which only 0.1% of pixels are brighter than.

   ```
   topIntensity = prctile(grayScaleImg(:),99.9);
   ```
3. Locate the pixels with intensity greater than this (i.e. top 0.1%) and place in a logical index array for reference.

   ```
   logicalIndices = grayScaleImg>topIntensity;
   ```